# id & name changed everytime WebDriver runs selenium webdriver way2sms

Tags: selenium

I'm writing a Java WebDriver code to send SMS from way2sms.com but I'm failing to insert mobile no in the box.

Below is the fraction of page from which I'm trying to insert any no in text box, I've already tried className(), cssSelector(), id(), name(); but nothing's working. Actually the problem is id="tQTSajQW" and name="tQTSajQW" change every time I run my WebDriver program.

driver.get("http://site2.way2sms.com/content/index.html");

```
    driver.findElement(By.id("username")).sendKeys("9xxxxxxxxxx");

    driver.findElement(By.id("password")).sendKeys("xxxxxxx");

    System.out.println(driver.getTitle());

    driver.findElement(By.id("Login")).click();


    driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div")).click();

    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='quicksms']")).click();

    driver.findElement(By.id("textArea")).sendKeys("9xxxxxxxxxx");
```

this is not working please Help on this

Comment: When you say "this is not working", what _exactly_ are you referring to? The link to the page requires login, so we cannot look at the code. Also, nothing in your sample code refers to "tQTSajQW". The only thing I can offer is: have you considered the documentation? http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/appendix_locating_techniques.jsp

Comment: Thank's for U r Answer Sir. the problem is i am write a code way2sms in selenium. in mobile number column error is coming element is not found. in mobile number column id changing dynamically. so i cont find the location pls Help on this

Answer (score 0):

Try finding element(s) thru cssselectors or tagname (iterate and access your element). CSSSelector is a great option to handle elements with Dynamic ids.

http://saucelabs.com/resources/selenium/css-selectors

Comment: way2smns code in selenium web driver please.i am trying but error is coming. please help on this

Answer (score 0):

If the object you are trying to refer is inside any parent object like table then you can use the id of the parent object to reach to this object dynamically.This approach is basically xpath-axis where we can reach an object based on relational objects at runtime.